# Google Maps API for Android - detecting buildings/obstacles between me and location

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Hypothetical question. I'm building an augmented reality app using Google Maps API for Android. I'm wondering if there's any data that I can use to determine whether a building lies between me and a specified location. I ask this because when sufficiently zoomed-in, there is clearly 3D data on the shape of buildings included on the map. I was wondering if there was a method like:

```
boolean buildingInTheWay(myLocation, destinationLocation);

if (buildingInTheWay) {
//Do something 
} else {
//Do something else
}
```

Perhaps there's also something that could be done where if the route to a location is much longer than the birds-eye path to a location, there must be an obstacle in the way (imagine two parallel streets like so:

```
- = street
X = buildings
A = start location
B = destination location


---------C----A-------
xxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxx
---------D----B-------
```

Here, A to B would return true, as the route around the buildings is a lot longer than the direct distance. But C to D would return false, as the route following a road is almost exactly the same distance.

However, that's not very accurate - what about *between* buildings? I wonder if each building on Google Maps has lat/lng points for each of its corners?

Any thoughts, anyone?

Comment: Very interested in the answer to your question, did you ever get this working? I'm basically looking for the same thing but also did not found an answer so far.